# The odds of winning two lotteries back to back

Tags: probability

Not one with a math background I ask the following question; what are the odds of winning both the Mega Millions and PowerBall back to back? A question that arose out of my statement to a friend’s question concerning odds in/against such such an event happening, with my answer being that it had to be the billions or trillions to one, to which he said no way.

This formula works well for each separately using MS-Excell:

Powerball-175,223510/1 odds using (combin(59,5)*35) as the formula
Mega Millions-258,890,850/1 odds using (combin(75,5)*15) as the formula

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two events are independent (being two different lotteries, I assume),  the probability of both events happening is the product of probabilities, that is 
$$
\frac{1}{175,223,510}\cdot \frac{1}{258,890,850} = \frac{1}{45,363,763,443,883,500}
$$
The denominator is about 45 quadrillion.